# How font-family declaration works in CSS?

Tags: css, syntax, font-family

[It's screenshot of the code I am working with. I want to understand the font-family declaration syntax and in what sequence it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Ogn.png)

Here's the code:

```
body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto",
        "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Basically I want to understand the font-family declaration syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font family is applied in order from the font you entered first.

For example, if a user's PC does not have a font, it is applied in order from the very beginning.

if there is a corresponding font, the fonts that follow the applied font will not be applied.

If the font name contains spaces, use quotation marks to indicate that it is a single font.

I'm not good at English, so I don't know if I delivered it correctly, but I hope it helped.

Comment: in MDN docs, the following syntax is valid:
font-family: Gill Sans Extrabold, sans-serif;
font-family: "Goudy Bookletter 1911", sans-serif.
How fist one is valid with out having quotation ?

Comment: Quotes should never be used around vendor prefixed system fonts such as -apple-system and BlinkMacSystemFont @shahriajamankhan

Comment: It's written at the bottom of the MDN. Generic font families are a fallback mechanism, a means of preserving some of the style sheet author's intent when none of the specified fonts are available. Generic family names are keywords and must not be quoted. A generic font family should be the last item in the list of font family names. The following keywords are defined @shahriajamankhan

Answer (score 2):

The font-family property can hold several fonts. If the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font. **If the browser supports "Segoe UI" it will be "Segoe UI" otherwise it moves to next**.

> So as a best practice order your fonts in the order you need.